# XML or SQL for processing large amount of data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, xml

I have been told to create  forum functionality in our website..I have done it using C#,SQL server,But my Boss insists he needs the datas to be stored in some physical file (xml or text).will using xml file for storing and retriving data cause perfomance issues.. Which is best suited for large amount of data sql or xml?

Comment: How are you planning on managing concurrency with an XML file?

Comment: SQL Server has a physical file; it's just not human readable. If you use XML you are just going to need to replicate all of the functionality that you get in SQL for free. Sounds like a really bad idea to me.

Comment: i have no idea regarding that since am new in using XML.. so i just need to know whether its possible using XML or text file instead of database..will the performance of XML or text file be better than SQL database

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from storing your data in SqlServer tables and then 'serving up' xml on request?

Comment: @Hugh Jones-My Boss feels storing large amount of data (since forum may have lot of interactions ) in database may slow down the website totally..is it true?

Comment: @karthi - Utter nonsense I'm afraid.

Comment: This is realy difficult to answer without knowing the details of what you are proposing.  Your boss may be right if you know that demand will stay constant, but for storing large amounts of, say, historic data, the database solution is the most scalable.  What data exactly are you going to be storing ?  How long do you want to retain it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you store data in a database, then it is stored in a physical file. You just get a robust bit of software that can read the data, and perform optimised searches, sorts, updates and take care of issues such as multiple processes trying to write to the file at the same time while being able to rollback transactions and so on.

You could store that data in an XML file and then build your own software which takes care of all of the above … but that would be a huge wheel to try to reinvent.

XML makes for a decent transport format for hierarchal data, but is a poor storage format for data you are actively working on. Use it for import / export, not storage.

Comment: @quentin-What about text files instead of xml..sorry if my question sounds stupid

Comment: Text files suffer from the same problems as XML, except that they have no structure in the first place, so you would have to invent a new data structure in addition to everything else.

Answer (score 1):

When your boss specifies a technical constraint on the solution, there are two possibilities: either he/she has a good reason (which may or may not be a purely technical reason), or he/she is misinformed. Ask him/her to explain what benefits the business is looking for by adopting approach X. Only when you have an answer to that question will you be able to formulate a case for adopting approach Y that has any chance of swaying the argument, and only by telling us the answer to the question will we be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

data in a database is a physical file.

maybe perform exports to the format of your choice.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: disagree. it is essentially the same answer as the selected answer above - but less verbose.